# R: change line/river color of shape file

Tags: r, layout, colors, shapefile

I am trying to create a map using R, showing rivers in different shades of blue and of different line widths for the TYPE attribute, but somehow I cannot seem to do this for the shapefile I downloaded here:

https://www.worldwildlife.org/pages/global-lakes-and-wetlands-database, glw-2

The rivers are always drawn as black lines of similar widhts although I specified both the line width and color.

This is what I tried and what works for other shape files:

```
riv2 <- readOGR("path\\wwf_65sv5l285i_GLWD_level2", "glwd_2", stringsAsFactors = T) 
riv2_crop <- crop(riv2, extent(-20, 45, -20, 15)) #cropping to save time/computational power
linewidth <- c(2,1,1)[riv2_crop$TYPE]
color <- c("#00a0a0","#3bd2c0","#3bd2c0")[riv2_crop$TYPE]
plot(riv2_crop, col=color, lty=linewidth)
```

If possible, I'd prefer to do it without ggplot